# Markdown quirk on bold and italics

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

```
***SomeText***
```

gives

***SomeText***

but

```
***Some_Text***
```

gives

***Some_Text***

It seems as though there's interference with the underscore character, since it can be used itself as markup for italics. Only it doesn't kick in at all, and it's not in first or last position.

Comment: It's partly because the underscore also does __bold__ (`__bold__`) and _italic_ (`_italic_`)

Comment: This is not a bug, it's a feature of nested incomplete format markup.

Comment: I was trying to implement a simplified markup myself. My approach was to cut up text by space (think of split in java). Ever string that started with a markup sign was a markup start, and every string that ended with a markup sign was a markup end.

Comment: tl;dr It's not a feature if it's not expected to work that way. It's a limitation.

Comment: Currently, the second example shows `concatenate("Some", "_", "Text")` in both bold and italics. That's what I'd expect. Maybe the fix fixed the example. Anyone remember what it showed before the fix? Did it swallow the underscore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is will [behave as expected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229236/115866) after the next build.

Comment: Just quoting: `***text***` now renders as `<strong><em>text</em></strong>`

Answer (score 18):

Escape the underscore with a backslash.

```
***Some\_Text***
```

***Some_Text***

Comment: Oh, that is a nice workaround!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the unambiguous [HTML](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user) syntax:

```
<em><strong>Some_Text</strong></em>
```

> ***Some_Text***

Or even mix the two:

```
<em>**Some_Text**</em>
```

> ***Some_Text***

Comment: That's what I did for my immediate need, but I'm just raising a flag on the bug. Thanks for the other workaround though.

Comment: @MPelletier I'm not sure it's a bug per se. Could just be a syntactical ambiguity. As ChrisF pointed out, asterisks and underscores work very similarly in Markdown.